# Alternative for SetModifiedProperty in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF5 Im using something like this to update a specific property in an entity.

```
_context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityObj).SetModifiedProperty("Password");
```

How can I do this in EF 6? I use this to update an entity in EF 6.

```
_context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
```

Im trying to achieve something like this:

```
foreach (var property in properties)//List<String> properties
            {
                _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityObj).SetModifiedProperty(property);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to only modify the properties that I identified

```
public TObject Update(TObject entityObj, List<String> properties)
        {

            var entities = _context.Set<TObject>().Attach(entityObj);
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                _context.Entry(entities).Property(property).IsModified = true;
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return entityObj;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF6, [they've modified that a little bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679512(v=vs.113).aspx). This is how your new call will go to [set a property's value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696346(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
_context.Entry(existing).Property(e => e.Password).CurrentValue = "Password1";
```

If you have a string value of which property to change, there is a separate overload for that.

```
_context.Entry(existing).Property("Password").CurrentValue = "Password1";
```

Comment: Can I do this without identifying the property? because I want to make it generic. in my method argument, the user will pass a list of string containing the properties to be updated.

Comment: There is a string overload for `Property()` as well, if you check out the MSDN I linked above.